# Delayed Jobs stops after some days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean, delayed-job, droplet

I'm running a prod environment of RoR 6 with a Digital Ocean Droplet. Everything works well but one thing, i manually run `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart` and seems to be ok, but after some days the process in charge of running the delayed jobs stops out of the blue, anyone knows why this could be happening?

I also tried to create a cronjob to set up the delayed_job process on a daily basis but it seems that is not working properly:

```
0 1 * * * 'cd /var/path/to/rails_project/ && RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart'
```

Comment: Can you please share size of instance? memory is one of the reason that stooping your job.

Comment: Sure! 
Premium Intel Shared CPU,
2 vCPUs,
4 GB - RAM,
80 GB - SSD Storage,
4 TB - Transfer

Comment: seems this is small instance, so probably job was stopped due to memory issue. You can monitor process via http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit it will give you more insights